# WCF: Get the returning value of the WCF via WebGet Attribute

Tags: wcf

I have this code inside my WCF Interface:

```
[OperationContract]
        [WebGet(UriTemplate = "/GetData/", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string GetData();
```

And this inside my Service page:

```
public string GetData()
{
     return "Please help";
}
```

I want to get the value of GetData function when I call it in url:

```
http://localhost: 12345/Services/MyWCF.svc/GetData/
```

After entering this url, I should be able to download the result inside the notepad due to JSON format.
I'm not sure what went wrong with my WCF.

Please help!

Please let me know if I haven't make my question clear.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How are you hosting your service? Are you sure it's running? Do any errors display when you hit the site?

Comment: Strange that my WCF runs in my browser but I fail to notice that I have a wrong service name. I just rename it and it work!. Anyway, Thanks for looking into my question ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The must use a specific binding & a web http behavior for this.
Suppose my service is under WebApplication1.Services.MyWCF, the config should be :

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"    />
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WebBehavior">
                <webHttp />
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="MyServiceBehavior" name="WebApplication1.Services.MyWCF">
            <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" contract="WebApplication1.Services.IMyWCF"/>

        </service>
    </services>
</system.serviceModel>
```

If you are under .Net 4, protocol mapping will also help you a lot. Look [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207338/Create-REST-Service-using-WCF).

Comment: I was able to solve my problem by renaming my service. I was able to run the WCF but haven't notice that I have a wrong service name. Any way, Thanks for your solution. I believe that should work too. ;)